# How to access settings in Pokémon Go when the top of the screen is unresponsive?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a crack at the top of my Sony Xperia Z3 Compact and the touchscreen at the top is completely unresponsive. I was wondering if anybody had a solution which would enable me to access the settings in Pokemon GO?

Comment: Fix your screen...?

Comment: I already got it fixed and it is so ridiculously fragile it cracked after 2 days when I put it in my bag with nothing but jumpers and left it on a bench for 30 seconds and last time it cost me £80 to repair

Answer (score 1):

With the Set Orientation app you can set your screen to be 180º rotated. its a temporary fix, while you repair your mobile

also, you can connect a mouse via usb or bluetooth

Comment: I think someone else mentioned using the zoom for the visually impaired feature on your phone under Accessibility in Settings.

Comment: @ekmod, yeah that should work too. also, you can connect a mouse via usb or bluetooth